# From a ratio $q_1 = x_1/x_2$, how do I compute $q_2 = x_2 / (x_1 + x_2)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is mostly in the title.  If I have a numerical value for a ratio $q_1 = x_1/x_2$, how do I compute $q_2 = x_2 / (x_1 + x_2)$?

For example, if $x_1 = 1$ and $x_2 = 8$, we would be given $q_1 = 0.125$ (without explicitly being given $x_1$ and $x_2$), and we would want to find $q_2  =8 / (8+1) = 0.88888...$

How does one generate $q_2$ from $q_1$ without access to $x_1$ and $x_2$?

Comment: $$\frac{1}{q_2} = \frac{x_1}{x_2} + 1 = q_1 + 1$$

Inverting both sides gives that $q_2 = 1 / (q_1 + 1)$.

Comment: @user61527:  that should be an answer.  Please post it as such so we have one.  Thanks

Comment: In your line For example, it should be q1=0.125

Comment: @RossMillikan Fair enough - I tend to dislike answering if it's a one or two line answer (and I see that Jika has already left a longer answer).

Comment: @user61527:  I think one or two lines is fine if it answers the question, which yours does.  But we do have an answer with a few more steps, so no problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have $$q_1=\dfrac{x_1}{x_2},$$

and 
$$q_2=\dfrac{x_2}{x_1+x_2},$$

Divide the numerator of $q_2$ and the denominator of $q_2$ by $x_2$. You will get:

$$q_2=\dfrac{\dfrac{x_2}{x_2}}{\dfrac{x_2+x_1}{x_2}},$$

which, as you can see equals:

$$q_2=\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{x_1}{x_2}}=\dfrac{1}{1+q_1}.$$